# set max-height flex parent, stretch nested child but inside of it overflow-y auto

Tags: html, css, flexbox, nested, overflow

I have some issues with the overflow of a nested flex child. I've set a max-height for the flex parent and let the child stretch themselves, to fit to their content. So far so good, but inside of the childs I've got some nested divs, ul and li. I only want to see the scrollbar inside of the ul, unfortunately it doesn't work. My content will get cut, due to the overflow: hidden. Height: 100% doesn't work for me either.

```css
.modal-column {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 1;
  padding: 0px 20px;
  max-height: 1300px;
  background:grey;
}

.modal-section {
  width: 320px;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 25px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  box-shadow: 0 0.25rem 0.185rem 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .04);
  cursor: default;
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-shrink: 1;
  flex-basis: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.section-status .modal-container {
  padding-bottom: 0px;
}

.modal-container {
  margin-bottom: 3px;
  padding: 15px 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.address-list-container {
  padding-top: 18px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.address-list-header {
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  padding: .5px 0px;
  width: 100%;
}

.address-list-tr {
  color: #7b7b7b;
  font-size: 12.2px;
  -webkit-box-pack: justify;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: stretch;
  display: flex;
  padding: .5 0px
}

.address-list-th {
  padding: 0px 5px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 1;
}

.address-list-ul {
  margin-top: 18px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.address-list-li {
  -webkit-box-pack: justify;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: stretch;
  display: flex;
  padding: 7.5px 0px;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted #d6d6d6;
}

.address-list-li:first-child {
  padding-top: 0px;
}

.address-list-li:last-child {
  border-bottom: none;
}

.address-column {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 1;
  font-size: 13.5px;
  padding: 0px 5px;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<div class="modal-column">
  <section class="modal-section section-status"></section>
  <section class="modal-section network-section">
    <div class="modal-container">
      <h2 class="modal-title">Network</h2>
      <div class="address-list-container">
        <table class="address-list-header">
          <tr class="address-list-tr">
            <th class="address-list-th">Name</th>
            <th class="address-list-th">Address</th>
          </tr>
        </table>
        <ul class="address-list-ul">
          <div class="address-list-li">
            <div class="address-column adress-key" title="1">1</div>
            <div class="address-column adress-value" title="123">123</div>
          </div>
          ......
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section class="modal-section app-section">
    <div class="modal-container">
      <h2 class="modal-title">1</h2>
      <ul class="bs-list-ul">
        <li class="bs-list-li">
          .......
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your css.

```
. address-list-ul{
     overflow-y:scroll; /*Try this instead*/
}
```

Hope this could help.

Comment: thanks for the reply. I tried it but it doesnt work out